# Concatenate variable to table element to compare three tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I'm using Alpha Anywhere to take a SQL query that my company uses to create a grid.
The query is as follows:

```
SELECT t.name,cat.description,i.item_num,i.type_of_unit,i.brand,i.pack,i.description2
FROM cim i, tname t, cim cat
WHERE 'P'||i.price_book_code=t.nameid and i.price_book_group=cat.item_num and i.category!=95 and
i.buyer_num!=8 and cat.warehouse_num=0 and i.broken_case != 'Y' and i.item_num not in (select
item_num from proprietary_items)
ORDER BY t.name,cat.description,i.description2, type_of_unit;
```

In the Where clause, 'P' is concatenated to i.price_book_code to equal t.nameid because all those values have a P at the beginning.

This query works fine in sql-developer, however alpha anywhere will not run it. It claims invalid token at the 'P' level. Apparently this type of concatenation is not compatible to portable SQL. Is there any other way I can concatenate and compare?

Thank you,
Howard

Comment: Have you tried to change order? : t.nameid = 'P'||i.price_book_code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CONCAT function should work. Here's an example of using it in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM dual
WHERE CONCAT('Foo','Bar') = 'FooBar';
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm still a beginner in SQL but that works perfectly.